# How can I get the wall clock time of a running process?

Tags: linux, process, time

I started a hash check of a large file and don't want to restart it using `time`. How can I get the wall clock time without using time at the beginning or using `date` right before I invoke a command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a running process you can do this:

```
PID=5462
command ps -p "$PID" -o etime
command ps -p "$PID" --no-headers -o etime
```

As a general feature you can modify your shell prompt. This is my bash prompt definition:

```
TERM_RED_START=$'\033[1m\033[31m'
TERM_RED_END=$'\033(B\033[m'
PS1='\nec:$(ec=$?; if [ 0 -eq $ec ];
then printf %-3d $ec;
else echo -n "$TERM_RED_START"; printf %-3d $ec; echo "$TERM_RED_END";
fi) \t  \u@\h:\w\nstart cmd:> '
PS2="cont. cmd:> "
```

The relevant part for you is the `\t` for the time.

This does not solve all problems, though. The new prompt will show when the process has ended but the former prompt may have been quite old when the command to be measured was started. So either you remember to renew the prompt before starting long running commands or you have to remember the current time when you want to know how long the current process will have taken.

For a complete solution you need an audit feature (which logs the start and end time of processes). But that may cause a huge amount of data if it cannot be restricted to the shell.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon the accepted answer, you can also continuously monitor elapsed time of a running process using `watch`:

```
PID=5462
watch command ps -p "$PID" -o etime
```